# Is it safe to call std::cin.putback(), std::cin.unget() without preceding them with a read operation?

Tags: c++, io, cin

Is it safe to call `std::cin.putback` without receding it with a read operation?

```
std::cin.unget(); // is it safe?

char c{};
std::cin.putback('V');
std::cin.get(c);
std::put(c); // V
```

- I wander what `unget()` does on an empty iinput stream?
- Because as I may think the read pointer is already at the beginning of the input stream and `putback` decreases the position so is this Undefined Behavior in my case? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not undefined. Similar to other abnormal behavior on the stream (like reading characters after EOF is reached), it makes the stream "bad".

You can try:

```
std::cout << std::cin.fail(); // 0
std::cin.unget(); 
std::cout << std::cin.fail(); // 1
```

Comment: Thank you! One last thing: is it safe to pass any character to `putback` e.g: `std::cin.get(c); // 'A' std::cin.putback('H');`? As you can see the last character read was `'A'` but I passed a different argument `'H'` to `std::cin.putback()`.?

Comment: @Maestro You can read the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback). For `std::cin`, the badbit is also set.